# How to configure a SessionHandler with a SessionContext in Jetty?

Tags: kotlin, jetty, session-state

jetty-9.4.11.v20180605

I have one project where I'm very happily using Jetty by configuring it programatically (in Kotlin/Java code, not in .xml or .ini files).  I'm adding Jetty to an older project and it's working well, except for configuring the SessionHandler.  It looks like it never gets the SessionContext 'cause it blows up with a NPE here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionDataStore.newSessionData(AbstractSessionDataStore.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionCache.newSession(AbstractSessionCache.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.newHttpSession(SessionHandler.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSession(Request.java:1559)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSession(Request.java:1532)
```

The insufficient config code (in Kotlin) looks like this:

```
val sessionIdManager = DefaultSessionIdManager(server, SecureRandom())
server.sessionIdManager = sessionIdManager

val sessionHandler = SessionHandler()
sessionHandler.sessionIdManager = sessionIdManager
sessionHandler.sessionCache =
        DefaultSessionCacheFactory().getSessionCache(sessionHandler)

val dataStoreFactory = FileSessionDataStoreFactory()
dataStoreFactory.storeDir = File(someDir)
val dataStore = dataStoreFactory.getSessionDataStore(sessionHandler)

sessionHandler.sessionCache.sessionDataStore = dataStore
server.handler = sessionHandler
```

I think maybe I'm missing a SessionContext in AbstractSessionDataStore which is called from `SessionHandler.newHttpSession()`, but I don't know how to set that.  It looks like SessionContex is associated with SessionHandler by calling `sessionHandler.doStart()` which is protected in SessionHandler.  If this isn't possible, I think I could get by with a WeakHashMap instead of a true Session, but I'm assuming it's better to try to use the existing Session.

Comment: HttpSession will need a ServletContextHandler, please show the code you are using the initialize the ServletContextHandler and how you add/configure your SessionHandler against it.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt that was the problem - thanks!  I ended up reusing the ServletContextHandler I had made for processing JSP and it kinda works.  If you want to show me how to do it correctly in an answer, I'll gladly accept and upvote it.

Comment: your variable names are the absolute worst.

Comment: @user2223059 Gosh, that's embarrassing!  I've fixed the awful variable names (and found a compile-error which I also fixed).